# Generate Reference Number from Database Table

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, auto-generate

I am a beginner in ASP.NET using VB Code. I want to generate a Unique reference no by concortinating three column fields.

Example:

1. Column unique reference no (System Generated) - 10
2. Column with Product Code (User Entry) - APPLE
3. Column with Product Title (User Entry) - FRUITS
4. Unique ref No = FRUITS/APPLE/10

I want to concatenate this three fields to the column Unique Ref No.

Comment: What is the column for? SQL table, gridview.....

Comment: why don't you apply [unique constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use calculated column - at [database level](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1682) or at [dataset level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810291.aspx) as per your requirements.